# index of source file [apache]

Tags: apache, ubuntu, indexing, directory

Currently I have a website setup with apache on ubuntu.

I'd like to customize the "Index of" file (the one that comes up when there is no index.html/php/etc as defined under DirectoryIndex) to remove the line of text that says "Apache/x.x.x (Ubuntu) Server at domain Port #".

I'm not sure where this file is located (in order to locate it and edit it). Additionally, I'd like to know how to have Apache point towards a different file (e.g. comment out the indexof.file and have it point towards a customized indexof2.file).

Image of the "Index of" file that I'm talking about:

[image: Index]

Summary of my questions:
1) Where is the "Index of" file located
2) How can I direct Apache to use a different "Index of" file (when there are no index.html/php/etc in that directory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The automatic index Apache generates is handled by this module (available by default): https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html

The customisation options would be way to long to explain here but they definitely exist, and are detailed in the link above.

More specifically, you want to have a look at the styling options from this chapter: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions

You can also find "premade" option packages like this one: http://adamwhitcroft.com/apaxy/

It's probably worth looking at this to understand how it works and get a good example of what's possible.

In this specific example, there's a lot of `IndexOptions` involved, as you can see in https://github.com/AdamWhitcroft/apaxy/blob/master/apaxy/htaccess.txt

Definitely not something easy to implement as this not just a file to edit, like you would edit a template, but there's room for customisation.

Comment: Thanks for the very informative reply.

From what I'm seeing from the example (apaxy) the [easy] way to go is to simply change it after the default index of has been rendered.

To remove the line stating the server OS I simply added  
`IndexStyleSheet /style.css` to my .htaccess file. whose contents were simply
`address {display: none;}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Capsule's response, I was able to research in a more meaningful manner and I stumbled upon a nice guide. For anybody who may visit this stackoverflow question of mine in future and is looking for a guide on editting the "Index of" directory page, the guide may help you too: https://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/